# Access action getters in the JSP

Tags: java, jsp, web-applications, struts2, jsp-tags

I am new to Struts and I have some values in the `Action` class that I would like to access in the JSP.  How can I access these values?

```
public static String[] getSoldItemsColNames() {
    return SellerHistory.soldItemsColNames;
}

public ItemType[] getActiveItems() {
    return sellerHistory.getActiveItems();
}
```

This is how I am trying.

```jsp
<s:iterator value="soldItemsColNames" status="soldItemsColNames" var="element"> 
<th><s:property value="%{#element}" /></th> 
</s:iterator>
```

Comment: whats the issue u r facing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my program - works perfectly:

```
 Action class : 
 static Account[] account=new Account[1];
 static String[] arrayofStrings={"1","2","4"};
 {
    Account a=new Account();
    a.setName(arrayofStrings);
    account[0]=a;

 } 

 //..getters and setters , execute()

  public String[] getArrayofStrings() {
    return this.account[0].getName();//Just like yours
  }
```

#### JSP Logic

```jsp
  <s:iterator value="arrayofStrings" status="true" var="element">
  <p><s:property value="%{#element}" /></p>
  </s:iterator>
```

Comment: I am not sure why, but in my case it works once i remove the static keyword. funny.

Comment: @ArunAbraham that is because accessing static methods via OGNL is a security risk (consider that OGNL is used to evaluate request parameters, and that sensitive system resources can be accessed statically).  So, by default, referencing a static method does not work in Struts2.  However you can turn it on with a configuration setting, but because of the security risk it is much better to access the static resources through an instance variable rather than directly.